# Connecting Linux and Windows Amazon EC2 instances through SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, cygwin

I have reserved a Linux and a Windows instances in Amazon EC2.  I would like to access between the two through SSH. I have installed cygwin (with openssh package) in the Windows instance.

How should I configure it for accessing to the Linux instance?  How should I configure access from it?

Answer (score 1):

Start with [Configuring SSH](http://www.mines.edu/~gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html) and let us know if you have a more specific question.